# What is the best way to handle custom error cases using AJAX?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, http, error-handling

When returning responses to an AJAX request, I am returning errors such as the following:

```
res.status(403).send("Member not found");
```

Say however, I have many similar error cases to return that use the same status code for example:

```
res.status(403).send("Member not verified");
```

What would be the best way to handle these cases separately within the error function of my AJAX request?

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/portal/change-email',
    data: data,
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (additionalEmailId) {
      //alert("Change email ajax success");
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
      //Deal with each error here
    }
  });
```

Comment: Don't send them as HTTP errors, as those should be reserved to indicate the status of the **request**, not the payload.

Comment: So what would be an alternative?

Comment: There is no *best*, because that is an opinion. But you could send the response as an object with a `status` property which indicates if it is a success or an error, and a `data` property with the send payload. Then check on the frontend what the value of the `status` property is and act accordingly.

Comment: That's essentially what I am doing though? Sending an error status 403, then the payload is the error message to display. The question asks how to distinguish between different errors with the same status. I could simply check which string the payload equals? Eg. if (xhr.responseText == "Member not found")

Comment: Sure, that's possible. But instead of sending strings and comparing them send an code which maps to an error string. For example: `{ '10': 'Member not found' }`. In this pattern you can define a small lib with error messages which is easy to maintain and select them trough the key of the error code: `const message = errors[code]`.